# Querying a derived type's attributes when using inheritance in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Using Doctrine's `QueryBuilder`, how can you specify a *where* condition on one of the attributes of a derived type when using single table inheritance.

Say I have a type `AbstractBillingEntity` which has a derived type `ComplexBiller`. `ComplexBiller` itself has a protected Doctrine controlled attribute called `organisationCode`.

**How can I use the `QueryBuilder` to search for all billing entities that are of type `ComplexBiller` and have `ComplexBiller.organisationCode > 5`?**

```
        $queryBuilder->andWhere("billingEntity INSTANCE OF ComplexBiller")
        $queryBuilder->andWhere(??)
```

*Using Doctrine 2.4, PHP 5.6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is an old problem that the Doctrine team currently won't fix ([DCC-16](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-16))

Apparently the internals of the Doctrine DQL language make it an exhaustive effort to try and implement a form of casting. While it may be considered in the future, the workout was to perform a sub-query with explicit requirements on the child class:

```
$subExpr = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("anEntity")
        ->from("ChildClass", "anEntity")
        ->where("orgEntity.derivedTypeAttr = :someParam");

$mainExpr = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->in("billingEntity.id", $subExpr->getDQL()))
            ->setParameter("someParam", $myVal);
```

Or, in native SQL (taken from the very useful source [here](http://stackoverflow.xluat.com/questions/8496621/doctrine-dql-class-table-inheritance-and-access-to-subclass-fields))

```
SELECT
    a
FROM
    Entities\Auction a 
INNER JOIN
    a.item i
INNER JOIN
    i.bookTypes b
WHERE
    i.id IN (
        SELECT 
            b.id
        FROM
            Entities\Book b
        WHERE
            b.type = 'Fantasy'
    )
```